# HTML & XHTML id attribute question

Tags: html

Can an id attributes value start with a number?

Comment: why dont u try it urself? what are the results.

Comment: I was going to post a snarky comment about just writing a basic HTML/XHTML page and validating it yourself on W3C, but then I realised that not everyone knows about the W3C validator. So heres a link :) http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For HTML, no - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Theoretically, the collection of legal values in XHTML could be much larger however I doubt it would be compatible with many browsers. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is actually incorrect.

All browsers have always supported ID attributes that start with a number, and HTML5 now allows it. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class:

> The HTML 4.01 spec
>   [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) that `ID`
>   tokens must begin with a letter (`[A-Za-z]`) and may be followed by
>   any number of letters, digits (`[0-9]`), hyphens (`-`), underscores
>   (`_`), colons (`:`), and periods (`.`). For the `class` attribute,
>   there is no such limitation. Classnames can contain *any* character,
>   and they don’t have to start with a letter to be valid.
>
> HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on [the `id`
>   attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute).
>   The only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document —
>   are that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be
>   empty), and that it can’t contain any space characters.

Note that you will need to escape the ID attribute value correctly if you want to use it in CSS or JavaScript. See http://mothereffingcssescapes.com/#123-foo.

Comment: This question is tagged HTML (the tag is for 4.01). Whilst many vendors implement extra features, to write portable applications, developers should stick to the specification unless there's a vendor specific workaround (such as the `-moz` / `-webkit` CSS prefixes).

Comment: @Phil 1) Where does it say the HTML tag is for HTML 4.01 only? That would be ridiculous. 2) Did you read my answer? The only reason this got specced in HTML5 is _because_ all browsers have always supported it that way. There’s no reason not to use this if you want to.

Comment: The `html` tag is for 4.01 (look on the [tag page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info)). There's a specific tag for [`html5`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5/info)

Comment: @Phil HTML5 is a subset of HTML, just like HTML 4.01 is. They’re not mutually exclusive.