# Is there a way to use URL query parameters and jquery animatedcollapse.js?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery's animatedcollapse for the FAQ section of my site, as a way to keep things tidy.

I have all the div's closed by default, but is there a way to have 1 specific div opened if I call the id with a URL query parameter?

The url I am referring to is: `http://www.carcityofdanbury.com/?cat=02&do=FAQ`
meaning if I have a link to `http://www.carcityofdanbury.com/?cat=02&do=FAQ#id=4` when the page loads can I have all the div's except #4 closed?

I've searched Google and cant find an answer for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method outlined here - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse_suppliment2.htm

For example - http://www.carcityofdanbury.com/?cat=02&do=FAQ&expanddiv=10004

Please note that your element IDs should not start with a number. See [HTML & XHTML id attribute question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084337/html-xhtml-id-attribute-question/4084353#4084353).

I'd also recommend you check out a more *up-to-date* plugin (dynamic drive, seriously?). Try the  [Twitter Bootstrap Collapse plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).

Answer (score 0):

Stick to all div's that you have attribute data-id = , then on $(document).ready() hide all div's that dont equal to 4

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $all_divs = $('#div');
    $all_divs.each(function(){
       if ($(this).attr("data-id") != 4) {
           $(this).hide();
       }
    });
});
```